# Firebase, query with "a child exists" as a condition?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database like this (photo attached): 
Trip has `BIDS`, and `awardedBid`. I use `awardedBid!=null` as a way to determine the trip is still available for bidding. However, I don't know how to query for that condition, so I have to hack by creating another field `bidDone` so I can use `.equalTo`, like this

```
mRootReference.child(CHILD_TRIPS).child(mTripKey).orderByChild(BID_DONE).equalTo(true)
```

However I feel that's unsafe when I have to use 2 keys to denote just one thing since it's bug-prone (I did create one myself in the attached screenshot where `bidDone = false` where it should be `true`).

Is there any cleaner way for that task: query with condition that a string exist?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can remove your attribute `bidDone` and using [`startAt()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data#data-order) to get all the child having `awardedBid` not null:

```
ref.orderByChild("awardedBid").startAt("")
```

or this to get only the child without bid

```
ref.orderByChild("awardedBid").endAt(null)
```

Comment: how about the other way round (`awardedBid==null`), so that I can switch between the two conditions, thanks