# Trouble filtering data in firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to filter some data from firebase database in a cloud function.
That data looks like this :

```
"items": {
    "id1": {
        "status": {
            "creation": timestampValue,
            "status": "initialized"
        },
        "data" : data1
    }
    "id2": {
        "status": {
            "status": "loaded"
        },
        "data" : data2
    },
    "id2": {
        "status": {
            "creation": timestampValue,
            "status": "loaded"
        },
        "data" : data
    },
    "id3": {
        "status": {
            "creation": timestampValue,
            "status": "ended"
        },
        "data" : data3
    }
}
```

I want to use a filter based on the creation field.
The field is not always present.

My code is inspired by this one :
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/delete-old-child-nodes/functions/index.js

here's the code I wrote :

```
const CUT_OFF_TIME = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 24 Hours in milliseconds.

exports.cleanAfter24h = functions.database.ref('/items/{itemId}').onUpdate((change, event) => {
    const ref = change.after.ref.parent; // reference to the parent
    const now = Date.now();
    const cutoff = now - CUT_OFF_TIME;
    const oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('creation').endAt(cutoff);
    return oldItemsQuery.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        // create a map with all children that need to be removed
        const updates = {};
        snapshot.forEach(child => {
            let childData = child.val();
            if (childData.status.creation) {
                let elapsed = childData.status.creation - cutoff;
                if (elapsed <= 0) {
                    updates[child.key] = null;
                }
            } else {
                console.log(child.key + ' does not have a creation date');
            }
        });
        // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
        return ref.update(updates);
  });
});
```

When the code is run, all items are retrieved, even those that have a timestamp smaller than the cutoff and those that do not have a creation field.
Any suggestions how to fix that?

I tried removing the items that have no creation field by adding a startAt("") before the endAt as suggested here :
[Firebase, query with "a child exists" as a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38440840/firebase-query-with-a-child-exists-as-a-condition)

```
const oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('creation')startAt("").endAt(cutoff);
```

Doing this I have no results in the query response.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
const oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('creation').endAt(cutoff);
```

into this:

```
const oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('creation').equalTo(cutoff);
```

> [`equalTo`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#equalTo)
>
> Creates a Query that includes children that match the specified value.
>
> Using `startAt()`, `endAt()`, and `equalTo()` allows us to choose arbitrary starting and ending points for our queries.

Comment: Thanks for you response.
But I'm not trying to get values equal to cutoff, I want to get values that are lower or equal to cutoff.

Comment: try `orderByChild('creation').startAt(0).endAt(cutoff);` Also when you do `const oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('creation').endAt(cutoff);`  you should be getting all the nodes that have creation less than cutoff or equal to cutoff..

Comment: I was indeed expecting to get values lower or equal to cutoff with :

    ref.orderByChild('creation').endAt(cutoff);
But it wasn't the case, I was getting all items regardless of their creation timestamp.
I will try with startAt(0)

Comment: did you try this `orderByChild('creation').startAt(0).endAt(cutoff);` though

Comment: I dit try orderByChild('creation').startAt(0).endAt(cutoff); and I get no results.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only workaround for now is to get all the items and then check them one by one to see if their creation is older than cutoff.